# Perforce .NET API Edit Files Not Checked Out

Tags: c#, api, perforce

I am trying to use the Perforce .NET api to Edit Files in my workspace to the default changelist. However, when I run the Edit Command it doesn't appear in the p4v front-end as if anything has happened. The files are still in the depot but not checked out. Is there an option I am missing or something else I need to include? The files definitely include a list of the files I am trying to check out but there is no obvious result of this command.

```
mPerforceConnection.Client.EditFiles(FileSpec.UnversionedSpecList(files), null);
```

I have tried adding options but they don't seem to get me anywhere. I don't want to add a changelist as I am trying to enter them on the default one so have entered 0 for that parameter.

```
Perforce.P4.Options options = new Options(EditFilesCmdFlags.None, 0, null);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the filename contained an @ sign. I thought other characters may have caused an issue. Didnt expect the @ sign to.